# How to navigate based on state using react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my react project, I'm using fetch api to get the user profile from backend. If there is any error occurred in the API call I'm showing it on the screen.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = React.useState("");

...

const handleGetProfile = async () => {
  await fetch(`${API_URL}/profile`).then(...).catch(err=>setErrorMessage(err.message))
  !errorMessage && navigate("/");
}
```

I wanted to navigate to root path only if **no error** occurred in the api call. So I'm checking if the error is empty and navigating to the root path.

The problem with this approach is that the `setErrorMessage` does not guarantee immediate update because it schedules the state update, so it is always navigating to the root path even if there is an error.

How do I solve this issue, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, because React state updates are asynchronously processed, ***and treated as `const`*** the `errorMessage` state won't have updated inside the `handleGetProfile` callback.

```
const handleGetProfile = async () => {
  await fetch(`${API_URL}/profile`)
    .then(...)
    .catch(err => setErrorMessage(err.message));
  !errorMessage && navigate("/");
}
```

It's also anti-pattern to mix `async/await` with Promise chains. Generally you use one or the other.

To resolve you should move the `navigate` call *into* the "resolved" part of the logic. Since `fetch` returns a Promise and ***only*** rejects on network errors you need to also check the response status.

See [Checking that the fetch was successful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)

> A [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) promise will reject with a [TypeError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError) when a
> network error is encountered or CORS is misconfigured on the
> server-side, although this usually means permission issues or similar
> — a 404 does not constitute a network error, for example. An accurate
> check for a successful `fetch()` would include checking that the
> promise resolved, then checking that the [Response.ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) property has
> a value of true. The code would look something like this:
>
> ```
> fetch('flowers.jpg')
>   .then(response => {
>     if (!response.ok) {
>       throw new Error('Network response was not OK');
>     }
>     return response.blob();
>   })
>   .then(myBlob => {
>     myImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
>   })
>   .catch(error => {
>     console.error('There has been a problem with your fetch operation:', error);
>   });
> ```

- Using Promise chain

  ```
  const handleGetProfile = () => {
    fetch(`${API_URL}/profile`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not OK');
        }
        // handle any successful response stuff
        navigate("/");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setErrorMessage(err.message || err);
      });
  }
  ```
- Using `async/await` with `try/catch`

  ```
  const handleGetProfile = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/profile`);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not OK');
      }
      // handle any successful response stuff
      navigate("/");
    } catch(err) {
      setErrorMessage(err.message || err);
    }
  }
  ```
- Use an `useEffect` hook to response to state changes

  ```
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [isFetched, setIsFetched] = React.useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = React.useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFetched && !errorMessage) {
      navigate("/");
    }
  }, [errorMessage, isFetched, navigate]);

  ...

  const handleGetProfile = async () => {
    setErrorMessage(null);
    setIsFetched(false);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/profile`);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not OK');
      }
      // handle any successful response stuff
      navigate("/");
    } catch(err) {
      setErrorMessage(err.message || err);
    } finally {
      setIsFetched(true);
    }
  }
  ```